# Nginx: how to start Nginx in case Nginx is not running?

Tags: nginx, cron

My Nginx stops running (after N months).
Is there a way to start it in case it is not running ?

Something like:

***if (nginx not running) restart or start nginx***

Regards

Comment: You should use a [process supervisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_supervision).

Comment: You can use `monit` to monitor nginx service and restart in case the service stops.